# Why would rocky earth-like planets be rare around white dwarf stars?

Tags: planetary-science, white-dwarf

I came upon an article here https://phys.org/news/2023-11-white-dwarfs-life-planets.html

The author thinks that rocky earth-like planets could be rare around white dwarfs.What could be the reason for this?

Answer (score 23):

**Short answer**

Most planets of this type may have formed too close to their parent star (the progenitor of the white dwarf) to have avoided being swallowed when it became a red giant.

Another possibility is that such planets, even if they could survive are either not scattered inwards so that they can be observed as transiting exoplanets or they do not survive that scattering process and get broken up by tidal forces.

**Details**

Rocky planets are likely to be formed close to their parent stars. It is only in the hot, dense parts of the protoplanetary nebula that sufficient rocky solids can form and aggregate into planets *without* also accumulating a big gas envelope.

The progenitors of white dwarfs will have gone through a red giant and an asymptotic red giant phase. During these phases their radii would swell to encompass a large fraction of the region where it is most probable that rocky planets would have formed.

If those planets are not engulfed immediately during that process then it is quite likely that they will spiral into the red giant star anyway on a short timescale, because their orbital periods will likely be faster than the rotation periods of the expanded giants. This raises tides in the giant star and extracts angular momentum from the orbit in order to spin the star up. As a result, the orbit decays and the planet will be engulfed.

It is possible (see below) that there are orbital radii from 1 au to a few au where rocky planets could form and might survive the red giant phase. For those planets then to be detected as transiting the remant white dwarf as short-period exoplanets they would need to be scattered inwards somehow. Another class of explanation for the lack of observed rocky transiting planets is that either they do not get scattered inwards efficiently or that they do not survive the scattering process, getting too close to the white dwarf and being broken up by tidal forces.

**Further details, comments and context**

This question has a number of nuances that my broad-brush answer rather skips over. If interested, then read on...

The context of this question is the recent paper by [Kipping 2023](https://arxiv.org/abs/2310.15219). The paper addresses the curious fact that the *only* confirmed transiting planet around a white dwarf is a giant planet. Kipping points out that if the distribution of stellar mass/radii is similar to that inferred from Kepler/TESS observations of short-period transiting exoplanets around main sequence stars then, that the first discovered transiting planet around a white dwarf is a giant planet would not be expected (with a probability $<0.5$%). Since white dwarfs are small light sources (roughly the size of the Earth) then finding transits from the the more common (in the Kepler/TESS samples) Earth-sized planets should be possible and in fact ought to be much more likely. Hence, Kipping claims that rocky *transiting exoplanets* around white dwarfs are rare.

i.e. The claim is actually that rocky planets *in short period orbits* are rare around white dwarfs, not necessarily that rocky planets are rare - though that is clearly one possibility to explain what is going on. Another is to think about how a transiting exoplanet gets to be where it is found. Such objects around a white dwarf cannot have formed in situ and neither can they have migrated there during the lifetime of the progenitor star. They must have scattered inward after the white dwarf had formed. So another possibility is that there is something inherently unlikely about scattering a rocky planet inwards and so even if they are relatively common at large distances from the white dwarf, they may not be found as transiting exoplanets. A variant of this explanation is that the rocky close-in planets invariably end up being broken into pieces by tidal forces and that might account for the observation of a number of debris disks around white dwarfs and the pollution of white dwarf surfaces by heavy elements.

A further nuance to this question (or at least to my answer) is that the likely critical dividing line between the formation of rocky planets and the accumulation of gas to produce giant planets is probably the [snowline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frost_line_(astrophysics)) (or frost line) beyond which more abundant ices could form. This line is at about 2 au for a solar-type star and this coincides (roughly) with the size to which a red giant Sun might swell up to.

However, the progenitors of the white dwarfs that exist today are predominantly stars that are *more massive* than the Sun, since these are stars that must have had short enough lives to have created white dwarfs within the lifetime of the Milky Way. The position of the snowline scales roughly with stellar mass, so the 1.5-2 solar mass progenitors of most of the white dwarfs we can actually observe today could have had snowlines at 3-4 au, that are *beyond* their radii as red giants.

Further, the progenitors of these white dwarfs must have lost significant mass during the red giant phase - via a powerful, radiatively driven stellar wind. This results in any planets that are around them moving outwards because of the reduction in gravitational binding energy. For a 1.5-2 solar mass progenitor, which loses 60-70% of its mass before becoming a white dwarf, this would increase orbital radii by factors of 2-3. Thus a planet at say 2 au (well inside the snowline for a $2M_\odot$ star) might end up in an orbit at 6 au and probably far enough away from any red giant to survive engulfment or tidal inspiral (tidal forces scale as $a^{-3}$).

Thus my answer is a simplification. It could be that there *is* parameter space to form terrestrial planets around 1.5-2 solar mass stars in wide enough orbits that they survive the red giant phase - in which case the lack of any detection of inwardly scattered examples around white dwarfs remains to be explained, which *is* the conclusion of Kipping's paper.

We actually know very little about the frequency of Earth-sized (and smaller) exoplanets in *wide* orbits around stars. Transit detection is only sensitive to short-period close-in planets. Doppler surveys are not yet sensitive enough to have detected Earth-mass planets at $>1$ au separations from stars. Microlensing has some sensitivity at orbital radii of a few au, but perhaps not to low enough masses. The plot below shows the inferred mass versus orbital radius diagram for exoplanets, colour-coded by discovery method - red for transits, blue for Doppler detection, green for microlensing and orange for direct imaging. I have marked on a domain where we might want to detect terrestrial planets at say $1-4$ au such that they might be able to form and yet survive the red giant phase. I have also circled in black the information for exoplanets around stars more massive than $1.5M_\odot$.

What you can see is a total absence of detected small exoplanets in this region. The absence *might* be genuine, in which case the lack of rocky transiting exoplanets around white dwarfs would be explained. But it could still be observational selection, since none of the techniques are really sensitive enough to detect exoplanets in this region of parameter space.

[image: Distribution of exoplanets mass vs orbital radius]

Comment: Hm, I wonder, if the mass loss during the supernova will also have an effect, in the other direction. If the star kept those rocky planets during the red giant phase, the sudden loss of mass will lead to destabilized orbits. Could this be enough to eject some of the planets? (maybe only when interacting with a third body)

Comment: @Chieron I have aded much more about this. Yes, mass loss could lead to some rocky planets surviving the red giant phase. If they are ejected though they could not be observed as transiting exoplanets! There is no supernova involved in the creation of a white dwarf - the mass loss is just via a stellar wind.